# Displaying different content on the same panel using Javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of anchor tags on a website. How can I change the content of a panel depending on which tag is clicked.  I don't want the page to change. I am guessing I will need to use JQuery but I don't want to use tabs. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When Anchor Clicked Trigger this to pull new panel, test.php would do the work.
then just insert the returned html.

You will have to include jQuery library

```
$.post("test.php", { PanelNum: Num},
   function(data) {
     $("#panel").html(data)
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        **code to change panel content, whether it be an 
        ajax request or simple $('selector').html()**
    });
});
```